# My Bootstrap Modal is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have tried a lot of different things and still can't seem to get my modal to work on this site. I've however had success on a different one of my sites so I am confused as to what the issue is.
Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Here is my code

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
<a href="#Modal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
<img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-1.jpg" alt="">
</a>
</div>
```

Modal Content

```
<div class="modal fade" id"Modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you missed equalto (=) in modal id `id"Modal2"`

Comment: I wonder how this worked on a different site then.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify data-target in your link

See example from Bootstrap site:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>
```

And don't forget to include bootstrap.js

Also you have an error

```
<... id"Modal2">
```

You forgot about "="

```
<div ... id="Modal2">
```

Hope it'll help you. If no, feel free to ask any questions, I'll try to help you.

Comment: I changed all these things and still not working? Any possible other reason?

Comment: I suppose that you didn't include some files or included not correctly.
See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shurshilin/tqtt751w/
I used your markup and it works.

And I included three files:
JQuery, bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css